# Display workflows in LOB application

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am working on a WPF LOB application. Basically users have to drive an entity(lets call it order) throuout the workflow. For example: The first one creates the order and it notifies his boss, then his supervisor confirms it,...

I would like to know if anyone knows any appropriate wpf user control for this kind of job. Most of the solutions on the internet are rehosting the WF designer. Unfortunately I do not have the time and resources to learn WF. I would prefer, to keep whole thing simple.